# Geometric logos

Tags: knowledge, geometry

Which famous company logos have the following geometric descriptions (listed alphabetically by company)?

1. Four congruent circles with six points of intersection
2. Regular pentagon containing five congruent triangles
3. Concave kite atop isosceles triangle
4. Hexagon partitioned into six congruent right triangles
5. Two inverted catenaries
6. Disk partitioned into three congruent sectors
7. Two-by-two array of congruent squares
8. Three congruent rhombi with a common point of intersection
9. Three concentric circles
10. Three mutually tangent ellipses with a common point of intersection

Comment: You might like this [2011 MIT Mystery Hunt puzzle](http://web.mit.edu/puzzle/www/2011/puzzles/katamari_damacy/charges/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

9/10:

> 1. Audi
>  2. Dodge/Chrysler
>  3. Delta Air Lines
>  4. HSBC
>  5. McDonald's
>  6. Mercedes
>  7. Microsoft
>  8. Mitsubishi
>  9. Target
>  10. Toyota

Comment: 4 is rot13(UFOP)

Comment: State Farm violates alphabetical order.  I added more detail to the description.

Comment: @RobPratt: Post updated.