# Geometric logos 2

Tags: knowledge, geometry

Following the idea of [Geometric logos](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/100073/geometric-logos).

Which famous company/software logos include the following geometric shapes (listed alphabetically by company)?

1. Three congruent parallelograms forming a hexagon with a hole in the center in the form of an equilateral triangle.
2. 14 congruent squares arranged in a 2x7 matrix.
3. Four identical right triangle
   trapezoids forming an octagon.
4. Two intersecting circles.
5. Rectangle.
6. Five congruent triangles forming a circle with a hole in the center in the form of a regular pentagon.

Hints for 6.

> One side of the triangle is a curve.

> This is the software logo.

Comment: rectangular trapezoids?

Comment: @truvortex_07, http://www.easycoursesportal.com/geometricalareas/course/Less-5.htm

Comment: its called a right triangle tho, search it up

Comment: Current answers have logos with *congruent* shapes of *different colors* listed for #1 and #2, even though the clues indicate the shapes are *identical*. Do the shapes need to be identical (same appearance, including size, shape, and color), or merely congruent (same size and shape)?

Comment: @NuclearWang, thank you for comment. They should be congruent only

Comment: is my answer for 6 right now

Comment: @truvortex_07, yes, you right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. 

> Google Drive

2. 

> Eighty20

3. 

> JP Morgan Chase (RobPratt and QuantumTwinkie)

4. 

> Mastercard

5. 

> National Geographic (QuantumTwinkie)

6. 

> Picasa

Comment: I have add the clue for 6.

Comment: I have added the second clue for 6.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Google Drive
> 2. Found in TruVortex_07's answer
> 3. JP Morgan Chase
> 4. Master Card
> 5. National Geographic
> 6. Perhaps a logo with a star inside of a circle?

Comment: I guess #3 has a J_______ prefix.

Comment: @quantumtwinkie, i have added the clue for the 6's logo.